# How to remove numbers in vector 1 from numbers in vector 2

Tags: r

Input:

```
temp_total_time <- c(1.24, 1, 54 , 1.89, 2.45, 34, 54, 6.91, 7.33, 85.42, 1.19)

break_time_vals <- c(2.24, 3.52, 1.24, 5,89, 1.89, 7.33, 17.54)
```

Output

```
opr_time_vals <- c(2.24, 3.52, 5.89, 17.54)
```

Code tried:

```
  my_list <- list(temp_total_time,break_time_vals)
  opr_time_vals <- sapply(my_list,remove_nums)
```

I want a code which executes very fast because I have vectors with length around `350000`, `10000`

Comment: What is `remove_nums` ?  You can use `%in% with `!` but these are floating point numbers

Comment: try `temp_total_time[!temp_total_time %in% break_time_vals]`

Answer (score 2):

There are probably faster ways... but this works.

```
zz <- break_time_vals[!(break_time_vals %in% temp_total_time)]
```

Comment: Other way around... break_time_vals[!(break_time_vals %in% temp_total_time)]

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for the `setdiff` function:

```
#R version 3.3.2 

temp_total_time <- c(1.24,1,54,1.89,2.45,34,54,6.91,7.33,85.42,1.19)

break_time_vals <- c(2.24,3.52,1.24,5,89,1.89,7.33,17.54)

setdiff(break_time_vals,temp_total_time)

[1]  2.24  3.52  5.00 89.00 17.54
```

here is the [Demonstration](http://rextester.com/live/NEU54346)

Answer (score -1):

I Found a solution now..

```
 temp_total_time <- trimws(temp_total_time,"both")

 break_time_vals <- trimws(break_time_vals,"both")

 opr_time temp_total_time[!temp_total_time %in% break_time_vals]
```

Comment: This is just the solution jalind posted, but with the extra `trimws()` step which shouldn't be necessary if your data is properly imported. If an answer helps you, you should upvote it and accept it, not post a copy of it.